# Ionic: Align Button in input with stacked label

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic5

I have some issues with ionic placing my button where I expect it:

[image]

I want my button to be on the same line as the input, like the clear-button.

This is my code:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label position="stacked">New answer</ion-label>
  <ion-input clear-input></ion-input>
  <ion-button slot="end">+</ion-button>
</ion-item>
```

I already tried to put the button inside the input as well - then it is on line, but the end-slot does not work there anymore. Is there any way I can do this? This should be the last line in a list. If I put the label in front of it, you can hardly see it is an input field at all.

Comment: add class on your `<ion-button slot="end" class="ion-align-self-center">`

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib Thanks. Center wasn't the right one, but ion-align-self-end did work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `class="ion-align-self-end"` to the button component